# React Router only rendering first Item

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to setup a react router and it's only rendering the first item in the menu I'm creating.  Here's some sample code.  Any idea what's going wrong?

```
import "./App.css";
import { HashRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Spot from "./components/Spot/Spot";
import Hero from "./components/Hero/Hero";

.....
        <div id="menu">
          <HashRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Hero />} />
              <Route path="/spot" element={<Spot />} />
            </Routes>
          </HashRouter>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the "first item" that is rendered? What menu are you referring to?

Comment: It renders the Hero element

Comment: And if you navigate from `"...../#/"` to `"...../#/spot"` the `Spot` component renders?

Comment: yes, maybe I don't under stand how this is supposed to work.  I want to create a menu with the two items...it will actually be more in the end.

Comment: The code you've shared is for routing, e.g. conditional rendering of React components/UI based on the current URL path. It's not clear what menu you are referring to.

Comment: oh, I want to make a menu with 3 items hero, spot, and home....that go to the corrresponding route. I'm realizing I'm not understanding this quite correctly though.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the routing. It is not like other components. This is routing. So, it defines the routes for the application. If you want to create a menu, you need to create Menu Separately.

Comment: I think so, ok I need to make the routes with the router and then make a menu that links to those routes

Comment: Yes, links would be used in a menu to link to the pages you want.

Comment: Thanks to you both, if there's a way to give you an answer I will.